# Timer to reset Closing button once clicked back to it's "Before" state after 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, timing

Hey there i've been having some difficulties with trying to figure out how to reset a button back to its previous state once its been clicked on. I know it involves a javascript timing, Can anyone help ive been trying all morning now.

```
    function clickMute()
    { if (document.Mute.src=='http://www.showandtell.com/TRUMusicControl/images/BeforeClickMute.png'){

    document.Mute.src='http://www.showandtell.com/TRUMusicControl/images/AfterClickMute.png';
    } 
    else if (document.Mute.src=='http://www.showandtell.com/TRUMusicControl/images/AfterClickMute.png'){

    document.Mute.src='http://www.showandtell.com/TRUMusicControl/images/BeforeClickMute.png';
    }
    }




    <div id= "Mute">
    <a href="#">
     <img id="Mutebutton" name="Mute" onclick="clickMute()" src="images/BeforeClickMute.png" width="140" height="126" />
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove the `a` (anchor) tag surrounding the image (mute button). Then just use the following code (to replace your function):

```
function clickMute(){
    var strPath = "http://www.showandtell.com/TRUMusicControl/images/",
        arrSrc = ["BeforeClickMute.png","AfterClickMute.png"],
        button = document.getElementById("Mutebutton"),
        index = (/Before/i.test(button.src)) ? 1 : 0;
    button.src = strPath + arrSrc[index];

    /* If you need the button to reset itself after a certain time... */
    if (index) setTimeout(clickMute,2000);
}
```

Comment: Here's what I'm doing: 1) Create an array with the source -- so you have less repetition and easier maintainability. 2) Create a regular expression with the "keyword" (Before) to test the current source of the image ... if Before is in it use the After image. Otherwise, vice-versa.

Comment: hey thanks! but for some reason i doesn't work... doesn't the anchor tag make it so its clickable? i tried with your code but it didn't even shutter.

Comment: The onclick event attribute in your img element is all you need. Send me a link to the page where I can see the problem.

Comment: Let me know if adding the THIS keyword (see last answer edit above) didn't work. I don't have a login ... so I can't get to the correct page (your provided link takes me to a login page).

Comment: it hasnt worked i just updated it with (this) included but im not sure why it isnt working, it acts as just an image////Im updating the site live, its meant to be an app

Comment: Thanks... I saw the problem right away (the function executes just fine -- it just doesn't have the right context). Please see above edits. It should be fine now.

Comment: Hmmm do i have to give the Mute image a button tag as well or is that why "(this)" is part of the onlick?....i updated the php file but its still the same? UGGHH im so frustrated, but i REALLY appreciate your help joe

Comment: Just got done copying and pasting my above code into the console while on your page... works great... even swaps it back as planned (after 2 seconds).

Comment: And, sorry about the confusion with the THIS keyword... I've been writing more OO-paradigm JS code for awhile now and haven't done (inline) event attribute handlers in awhile... so, that was my bad. At least it works now.

Comment: Don't forget to delete your comments with the username/password and URL.

Comment: Thanks so much Joe, i dont know why it doesn't work on my side? It might be some spacing issues or something really small (i hope).